# Error "help: permission denied" when using ADB

Tags: adb

Using [this tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378), I installed ADB shell. I actually just wanted to mess around and see what can it do. My device isn't rooted but that's ok, I'm not trying to do anything dangerous. Just trying run normal user linux commands.

USB debugging is enabled.

So I typed:

[image: help adb shell permission denied]

What's that supposed to be? Is really exit the only supported command?

Comment: Does the command adb devices show your device? What other commands did you try? Try ls, mount, mkdir, cd, etc... and see if it works. Installing busybox from play store will increase your command repertoire.

Comment: The standard command for help in Linux is `man` for manual, not `help`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `help` is no actual command that comes with the Linux system (even though many systems like Ubuntu have one). If you would like to see valid commands, just list all files inside `/system/(x)bin` with the appropriate `ls <directory>` command.

If `help` is listed there then it may not be your usual help command you know from windows.

It may also be a limitation by the manufacturer so that terminal access is restricted to the system only.